# How to make query results accessible from all pages

Tags: node.js, templates, express, swig-template

I am trying to be able to pass a variable through to my template, I can get it to work for single pages but I need to find a way to access the results of it in any page. Reason being that it is needed for my sidebar that is part a a template.

My template is

```
include header

include sidebar

content

include footer
```

That is just sudo code and clearly not my actual code.

The query I need to include is:

```
Item.count({"author.id":req.user.id}, (err, itemCount)=>{
 if(err){
  console.log(err);
 } else {
  var Count = JSON.stringify(itemCount);
  // somehow I need to store Count to be accessible inside my sidebar
 }
});
```

I know that I could take and put the query inside each and every route but is there a way I can do it for only the logged in user and put it in a middleware or something or the sort?

I currently have it stored in each route but I know that it is not DRY code and that updating it will be a HUGE pain since I have over 50 routes I handle.

My typical route is:

```
// dashboard
  app.get('/dashboard',
    setRender('dashboard/index'),
    setRedirect({auth: '/login'}),
    isAuthenticated,
    (req, res, next) => {

    },
    dashboard.getDefault);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use middleware for that purpose, i.e.:

```
app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
    Item.count({"author.id":req.user.id}, (err, itemCount)=>{
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
           res.status(500).send(err);
       } else {
          req.Count = JSON.stringify(itemCount);
          next();
       }
    });    
});
```

That will execute your query in all routes and save the result in `req.Count`. If you want that to execute only in a certain set of routes, modify the `'*'` portion for any path you'd like to match. Also, you may want to extract your other middleware functions like `isAuthenticated` into their own `app.use` clauses so that you can manage the order more accurately.

Comment: Thanks, so to access it in the template I would just do `{{ Count }}` which would be syntax for swig/twig. As for including it, that would be a separate file or just put inside my app.js file? Change the `isAuthenticated`? It is it's own middlware right now called in a `var` by doing `var isUnauthenticated = require('./middleware/auth').isUnauthenticated;` Then including the var name later on. Is that not right for how to do it?

Comment: As long as you're referencing the same `app` you can put it anywhere you want, app.js should work or you can write the function in a separate js file, export it there and require it in app.js, your call. As for the authentication middleware, it's just a suggestion, you can achieve the same thing by doing `app.use('*', isUnauthenticated)` and you don't have to declare it in every route.

Comment: thanks I will keep that in mind when I redo my routes in the coming week or two. They are in need of a major overhaul. File is over 1800 lines and has every route in it. Way too stupid of me to not split it out from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work, I never knew about using app.use for this.